# How to add upload request property in background Transfer for windows phone 8?

Tags: windows-phone-8, file-upload, background-transfer

I am trying to upload audio file using background transfer method in windows phone 8. I have to add upload request property for uploading the file to the server successfully. Is it possible using "Tag" or  "Headers" property of the background transfer request??

Answer (score 0):

You can set the Headers in the

```
`BackgroundTransferRequest.Headers Property`
```

It is basically a `Dictionary<string, string>`

So you can `.Add(key, value)` to it

[MSDN Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/microsoft.phone.backgroundtransfer.backgroundtransferrequest.headers%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

---

Be careful, it looks like there are some header keys that are reserved.

Comment: server will receive a property named "userfile" and file name "song.m4a" for that property. I have tried using BackgroundTransferRequest.Headers.Add ("userfile","song.m4a"). But it's not working.

Comment: @bdcrhai that actually looks like POST variables not headers key-value pairs.

Comment: you are right. Is there any way to pass that variable to that upload request??

Comment: @bdcrhai I'm not sure, you can reword your question and see if anyone with more experience can answer it.